# Explain this code for me

Tags: apex, loop

```
         DateTime earliestCreated = events[0].CreatedDate;
                for(integer i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) { 
                    if(events[i].CreatedDate < earliestCreated) index = i; 
                }
            }
            system.debug('event index '+index);
            if(events.size() > 0)
            {
                events[index].RecordTypeId = stdEventRT;
                events[index].Description = c.Description;
                events[index].Subject = EVENT_REMINDER+c.Name;
                events[index].StartDateTime = c.Start_Date_Time_Main__c;
                events[index].EndDateTime = c.End_Date_Time_Main__c;
                events[index].Type = EVENT_TYPE;
                events[index].OwnerId = c.OwnerId;
```

Can someone explain the last line of the code?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! Our community thrives on specific, detailed questions. Can you [edit] your post to clarify what you do not understand or are struggling with? See [ask] for more.

Comment: The logic as written appears to simply be _wrong_, which may be a source of confusion, but we can help you more if you tell us what you are trying to do and the specific problem you have.

Comment: Hey @DavidReed, I updated the post to show more of the code

Comment: I'm not asking for more code, but for a discussion from you of _what problem or question you have_. "Explain this code to me" generally does not fit in SFSE's format, which is probably why your question is attracting some downvotes.

Comment: So the code is using the idea of a set list called Events and here's the list   List<Event> events = [select Id, RecordTypeId, Description, Subject, Type, CreatedDate, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, OwnerId from Event where WhatId = :c.Id and isrecurrence=false];
  system.debug('event '+events).  The question im having is what is  if(events[i].CreatedDate < earliestCreated) index = i; . I just need to know the reasoning for this individual line of code. I'm getting confused on that single piece.

Comment: The code (before you updated it) looked like it was attempting to find the index of the event that had the earliest `CreatedDate` but should have updated the `earliestCreated` when it updated the `index` hence David's comment that the code was likely wrong. Do also note David's comment about care being needed when you post a question if you want a good answer.

Comment: That is just finding (or trying to find, as pointed out by Keith C) the index in the array of events for the one with the earliest create date. There are definitely potential issues with the code (such as assuming the list isn't empty) and there are aspects that you have omitted (like the declaration and initialization of the index variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
if(events[i].CreatedDate < earliestCreated) index = i;
```

is *attempting* to find the index of the Event with the earliest CreatedDate. But it doesn't work: in fact, it finds the index of the last Event in the list with a CreatedDate earlier than that of the first Event in the list. It needs to *update* `earliestCreated` as it finds each earlier event.

There are a variety of other problems with this code, in particular that it does not check the size of the list before accessing the first element, and then does a check `if(events.size() > 0)` that does nothing (because if the list were empty, the code would have already crashed).

There may be other issues at a semantic level. I have no idea what this code is trying to accomplish, and what I can infer from the code seems like a pretty bad idea to me.

Comment: Thanks David, To be honest My boss wanted me to review a previous coworker code and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Your previous coworker did not know what they were doing. If you don't feel comfortable reading and evaluating Apex, I'd really recommend your company hire a consulting senior engineer to do a review. It will do neither you nor your company well to ask you to read and interpret bad Apex if you're not comfortable with it.